# How to set accessibilityIdentifier for navigationItem titleView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uiaccessibility

I have set accessibilityIdentifier for both leftBarButtonItem and titleView on view did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    title = "input_nickname_title".localized()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "btn-nav-left"
    navigationItem.titleView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "lbl-header"
}
```

but when testing using accessibility inspector, only the leftBarButtonItem is set

[image]
[image]

I also tried doing the following but it also shows identifier as none

```
navigationItem.titleView?.setValue("lbl-header", forKeyPath: "accessibilityIdentifier")
```

I only have problems setting the identifier I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622833/ios-accessibility-how-do-you-set-the-accessibility-label-for-the-title-of-a-ui) and it only touched on accesibilitylabel, one answer mentioned [adding uilabel to the titleView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116568/13329248), but I want to avoid it. and on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166652/swiftui-how-to-add-accessibility-identifier-on-navigationtitle) post, the answer says that

> I don't think this is possible in SwiftUI using .accessibility(identifier:) - it might be worth submitting feedback to Apple.

and I want to know whether it's also an issue with UIKit? and is there a way around it without adding uiLabel?